# Adjust pan not Working When Edit text Height Mentioned in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

i am usign adjustpan in activity it's scroll perfect when simple Edit text with single line but, it's not work properly in multiline edittext with height mentioned like below ediitext xml layout

```
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_feedback"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_to"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt_to"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="8"
            android:maxLength="160"
            android:minLines="6"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/textboxborder"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:hint="-- Your Comments --"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />
```

for current output below like screen:
[image]

and i am excepted output like below screen:

[image]

and how to do this somebody help me ?

Thanks :)

Comment: This question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292950/push-up-content-when-clicking-in-edit-text

Comment: I've so far found that I get either behaviors depending on the device I'm testing on. Although it's not dependent on android version.