# How to force android layout to shift upward when softkeyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, autoscroll

I have an activity with a text-view, 2 edit-text and a list-view all in vertical orientation, here list work as a auto suggestion list when we type in either of the edit-text, now the problem is when the list is populated with the suggestion result it always remain below the soft-keyboard i.e., if we have to check and select the result then we first have to hide the keyboard. Is there any way to pushup the activity layout so that list is visible only if it contains something I tried    `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"`
also but it doesn't help me :(

Please help.

Comment: try adding this android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in problem [Push up content when clicking in edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292950/push-up-content-when-clicking-in-edit-text), I also able to solve my problem by hiding/showing the view just above edit-text with soft-keyboard open/close event respectively. By doing so, I had enough space there to show the suggestion list even the soft-keyboard is in open mode. It appears as is tricky solution in my case too...

Answer (score 2):

We can use linearlayout to ajust.

Try this code：

Activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Layout:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, but it doesn't work here. Any other idea?

Comment: sorry, i was misunderstanding your problem, and i have revised my answer.

Comment: The input mode should be android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: Hi @kevinhoo, thanks for you efforts. it doesn't help me to achieve my goal because, may be, in my case list-view remain hide on load and shows only when it has data. No doubt, your code works proper in case if the layout is as suggested by you..

Comment: actually, you can fill the list with empty data. when the edittext is focus, pan the whole layout up. after you get the data, fill the list with real data.

Comment: I able to handle this scenario in some other way. please see my answer to the question.