# Change size of Listview when closing or opening Softkeyboard

Tags: android, listview, size

How can I expand my Listview when I close the Softkeyboard or open it again ? My Listview is currently full screened.

Problem: When I want to scroll to the last item of my ListView I have to close Softkeyboard first because the Softkeyboard is hiding it (so its under the softkeyboard) , and thats kinda annonying.

I found an example ,what I want to achieve, in the android music player search function which looks like this when I open and close it (See scrollbars)

[image: When Softkeyboard is closed]
[image: When its opened]

Is there a way without much hacks ? I allready tried this in my manifest :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

but this didnt helped.

EDIT:
My Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_background">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_searchbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_btn_back"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint=" Search"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:drawableBottom="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_btn_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText_searchbox"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText_searchbox"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_white_48dp" 
            android:onClick="btn_back"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout1">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try adjustPan? I think that is the scrolling input mode

Comment: Allready tried that and it is not working ... any other suggestions ?

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

Comment: My post is updated. Thanks for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292950/push-up-content-when-clicking-in-edit-text

Comment: I could find that the softkeyboard is opened with the hack. But how should I resize it then ,with which information (margin ?)?

Comment: Look at the top 3 answers, not the hack that is the accepted answer. It shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With zgc7009 help I found out that the `adjustResize` only works when the layout is **NOT** in fullscreen mode. That solved everything by changing my AppTheme style.

If someone knows how to use `adjustResize` with fullscreen mode let me pls know.

Thanks again to zgc7009 !