# How to prevent soft keyboard cover my views

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

In the layout file of one of my activities I've got 2 inputs at the top and at the bottom and a next button.

The problem is, when keyboard shows, it covers the button. How can I bring the views above keyboard?

Comment: search on google .

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android

Comment: Also related, perhaps even a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111813/how-to-move-the-layout-up-when-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown-android

Comment: This answer might be what you are asking to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this blog post [On-screen Input Methods](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)

You can use [android:windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) attribute to specify what should happen whether the layout is resized or whether it scrolls.

In your manifest file

```
<activity name=".YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
        ...
</activity>
```

Related questions:

[Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

[Push up content when clicking in edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292950/push-up-content-when-clicking-in-edit-text)

[Android: How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing my view up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up)

[How to move the layout up when the soft keyboard is shown android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111813/how-to-move-the-layout-up-when-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown-android)

[How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Just put in manifest..
Use "adjustResize"

It makes main window  always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

```
<application
......
>
<activity
           .............................
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" />

 </application>
```