# How to push the contents of a View up when Keyboard pops up?

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I have a `RecyclerView` and an `EditText` inside a `CardView` . Purpose of the activity is to chat. So the `RecyclerView` contains all the messages sent and received, and the `CardView` is where the user types the messages. Coming to the problem, I need to move the contents up when the Keyboard pops up. Now, this doesn't seems to be a simple problem.

I tried all these Questions:

- [Push up content when clicking in edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292950/push-up-content-when-clicking-in-edit-text)
- [How to move the layout up when the soft keyboard is shown android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111813/how-to-move-the-layout-up-when-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown-android)
- [Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

And, the solution to most comes down to altering `android:windowSoftInputMode` . Which I tried, switching to `adjustPan` and `adjustResize`. Here is the code to my Activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F0F0F0"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    tools:context="com.devpost.airway.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chatView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_input"
            android:paddingStart="2dp"
            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And `adjustPan` does work in a very vague way, I've added the screenshot below, kindly take a look :

**IMAGE-1**

[image: IMAGE-1]

**IMAGE-2**

[image]

Now, clearly from Image-1 and Image-2, there are few issues:

- The `ActionBar` is moved up .
- When Keyboard pops up it adds a transition animation
- It pushes the entire RecyclerView up

So, the **question** is:

Is it manually possible to override any methods and implement things myself up, other than allowing the `android:windowSoftInputMode` to change the way it prefers? Kindly help.

Comment: Hardly made any changes, doesn't do anything. @Ironman

Answer (score -1):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/chatView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editorCard"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/editorCard"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
 <!--your editor code-->
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

`wrap_content` and `layout_above` are the key changes for the desired behavior

and in `softinputmethod`, make it `adjustPan|adjustResize`