# keyboard covers half of the edit text Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I am developing an app and I found a problem that the keyboard hides the EditText Field. Upon researching i found a solution by adding this line of code in manifest file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

but now my edittext looks like [image: this]

the emoticon icon, edit text and the SEND textview are in a Linear layout. How do i show the entire linear layout above the keyboard  ??

Comment: Hope this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28012530/2347794) helps you ....

Answer (score 1):

Set  android:softInputMode attribute to adjustResize in Manifest and put layout(not list item layout) inside a ScrollView.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand the last part "put layout(not list item layout) inside a ScrollView."

Comment: I mean not put the scrollview for the layout of listview if you have used listview. You may ignore that. Please put the scrollview for layout where that edittext box, send button  and all come.

Answer (score 0):

i had exact same problem with `adjustPan` so i use this instead..

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

i hope your root layout is `RelativeLayout`.

**UPDATE**

try to set like this.

chat_ui.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/applayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Francis"
                android:textColor="@color/page_background"
                android:textSize="10pt" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@id/applayout"
        android:id="@+id/chat_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@drawable/chat_divider"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:transcriptMode="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/input"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">

            <!--  <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/emojiButton"
                  android:layout_width="24dp"
                  android:layout_height="24dp"
                  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                  android:src="@drawable/input_emoji" />-->

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/chat_edit_text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="@string/type_message"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textColorHint="#c4c0bd"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/enter_chat1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/input_circle_normal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in manifest

```
<activity
     android:name=".activities.ChatActivity"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme2" />
```

Comment: tried , didn't work :( it totally covers my editText

Comment: check my update.. its working code of my chat-app, its work good in my moto-g4 plus with nougat version

Comment: didn't work for me :( thanks for the updated answer though