# Bottomsheet Dialog hides UI elements

Tags: android

I am trying to use a bottomsheet dialog with edit text inside, I have these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

In the second image, the keyboard cuts the UI element, which should be pushed the layout up.

Here's my code

```
public void setUpBottomSheetDialog() {
    View bottomSheetDialog = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_layout2, null);
    bsDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
    bsDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetDialog);
    bsDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    bsDialog.setCancelable(true);
```

and

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:behavior_hideable="false"
app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bs_imv_tag"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bs_Etx"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.99"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="type your note"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:maxHeight="80dp"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textColorHint="#4e97bc" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bs_imv_save"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
</LinearLayout>
 <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Could you hint me out where to modify?

Comment: tried adjustPan and adjustResize in manifest, no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

[Reference this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292950/push-up-content-when-clicking-in-edit-text)